# Sum the results from different queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to sum the results of three different queries. Here's what I'm doing but the result is incorrect. If I run each query separately they are fine, but running them together I get different results.

```
select 'Inforce TIV',
ISNULL(SUM(a.TSI), 0)
+
ISNULL(SUM(b.TSI), 0)
+
ISNULL(SUM(c.TSI), 0)
from
(
    select ISNULL(SUM(p.[Suma Asegurada Inforce]), 0) as TSI
    from temp_portafolio_cy p
    --where p.fec_emi between @varFechaDesde and @varFechaHasta
    where p.fec_emi between '20160101' and '20160131'
    and p.sn_bancaseguros = 0
    group by p.cod_suc, p.cod_ramo_comercial, p.Poliza, p.Item
) a,
(
    select ISNULL(p.[Suma Asegurada Inforce], 0) as TSI
    from temp_portafolio_cy p
    --where p.fec_emi between @varFechaDesde and @varFechaHasta
    where p.fec_emi between '20160101' and '20160131'
    and p.sn_bancaseguros = -1
    and not (
        (p.cod_suc = 1 and p.cod_ramo_comercial = 34 and p.Poliza = 51385)
        or (p.cod_suc = 1 and p.cod_ramo_comercial = 26 and p.Poliza = 53231)
    )
    group by p.cod_suc, p.cod_ramo_comercial, p.Poliza, p.Item, p.[Suma Asegurada Inforce]
) b,
(
    select ISNULL(p.[Suma Asegurada], 0) as TSI
    from temp_portafolio_cy p
    --where p.fec_emi between @varFechaDesde and @varFechaHasta
    where p.fec_emi between '20160101' and '20160131'
    and p.sn_bancaseguros = -1
    and (
        (p.cod_suc = 1 and p.cod_ramo_comercial = 34 and p.Poliza = 51385)
        or (p.cod_suc = 1 and p.cod_ramo_comercial = 26 and p.Poliza = 53231)
    )
    group by p.cod_suc, p.cod_ramo_comercial, p.Poliza, p.Item, p.[Suma Asegurada]
) c
```

Comment: Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `JOIN` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: I do not know how to do the inner join (considering is the same table). Could you write an example based on query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a cartesian join of the 3 sets of results. 
You have 2 options:

1. Remove all the "group by" statements
2. Include the columns your grouping by in each of the 3 selects statements, and then add a where clause when joining them together (e.g. where a.code_suc = b.code_suc and b.code_suc = c.code_suc... etc.)

I would recommend option 1, as the "group by"s aren't really necessary in the example you gave and joining with where clauses will give you an implicit inner join

Comment: I was cheching eliminate group by and it is necessary due to duplicate values are being cond¿sidering if group by is eliminated. So, the second option is the best solution or simply add and temporary table where each statment results are loaded and the sum the values. Regards all

Answer (score 0):

The `group by` in the sub queries are probably causing you to get cartesian join on the results, i.e. causing wrong sum through multiplication. Maybe you could write like this?

```
select 'Inforce TIV',
ISNULL(SUM(a.TSI), 0)
+
ISNULL(SUM(b.TSI), 0)
+
ISNULL(SUM(c.TSI), 0)
from
(
    select ISNULL(SUM(p.[Suma Asegurada Inforce]), 0) as TSI
    from temp_portafolio_cy p
    --where p.fec_emi between @varFechaDesde and @varFechaHasta
    where p.fec_emi between '20160101' and '20160131'
    and p.sn_bancaseguros = 0
) a,
(
    select ISNULL(p.[Suma Asegurada Inforce], 0) as TSI
    from temp_portafolio_cy p
    --where p.fec_emi between @varFechaDesde and @varFechaHasta
    where p.fec_emi between '20160101' and '20160131'
    and p.sn_bancaseguros = -1
    and not (
        (p.cod_suc = 1 and p.cod_ramo_comercial = 34 and p.Poliza = 51385)
        or (p.cod_suc = 1 and p.cod_ramo_comercial = 26 and p.Poliza = 53231)
    )
) b,
(
    select ISNULL(p.[Suma Asegurada], 0) as TSI
    from temp_portafolio_cy p
    --where p.fec_emi between @varFechaDesde and @varFechaHasta
    where p.fec_emi between '20160101' and '20160131'
    and p.sn_bancaseguros = -1
    and (
        (p.cod_suc = 1 and p.cod_ramo_comercial = 34 and p.Poliza = 51385)
        or (p.cod_suc = 1 and p.cod_ramo_comercial = 26 and p.Poliza = 53231)
    )
) c
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is creating a cross join of three separate subqueries (a, b, c) which is going to generate rather interesting results if any of the subqueries return more than one row.

There are a number of ways to correct your query.  Let me suggest the one below which eliminates the need for the GROUP BY in the subqueries and, overall, simplifies the query.  (By the way, if the subqueries never return a null TSI value you can simplify the result column to ISNULL(SUM(TSI), 0).)

```
select 'Inforce TIV',
ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(TSI, 0)), 0)
FROM (
    select p.[Suma Asegurada Inforce] as TSI
    from temp_portafolio_cy p
    --where p.fec_emi between @varFechaDesde and @varFechaHasta
    where p.fec_emi between '20160101' and '20160131'
    and p.sn_bancaseguros = 0

    UNION ALL

    select p.[Suma Asegurada Inforce]
    from temp_portafolio_cy p
    --where p.fec_emi between @varFechaDesde and @varFechaHasta
    where p.fec_emi between '20160101' and '20160131'
    and p.sn_bancaseguros = -1
    and not (
        (p.cod_suc = 1 and p.cod_ramo_comercial = 34 and p.Poliza = 51385)
        or (p.cod_suc = 1 and p.cod_ramo_comercial = 26 and p.Poliza = 53231)
    )

    UNION ALL

    select p.[Suma Asegurada]
    from temp_portafolio_cy p
    --where p.fec_emi between @varFechaDesde and @varFechaHasta
    where p.fec_emi between '20160101' and '20160131'
    and p.sn_bancaseguros = -1
    and (
        (p.cod_suc = 1 and p.cod_ramo_comercial = 34 and p.Poliza = 51385)
        or (p.cod_suc = 1 and p.cod_ramo_comercial = 26 and p.Poliza = 53231)
    )
) x
```